# Watir, element of page object with several possible IDs

Tags: watir, page-object-gem

Imagine an element of page element like this:

```
link(:upgrade_link,              id: 'Upgrade')
```

Now, imagine that the Id of this link has a chance of changing in each test, to a different id : difference.

Is it possible to make something like this?

```
 link(:upgrade_link,              id: 'Upgrade' || id: 'difference')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match multiple possible ids, you could match the id by regexp. The regexp allows for multiple matching by using the `|`.

Your page object accessor would be:

```
link(:upgrade_link, id: /^(Upgrade|difference)$/)
```

Note that the `^` and `$` are used to ensure that the id exactly matches. Without them, you would match links with ids like 'Upgrade2', 'adifferenceb', etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ve found another solution:

```
link(:upgrade_link, xpath:"//a[@id = 'Upgrade' or @id = 'difference']")
```